# Unable to install Sqoop

Tags: 16.04

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and tried installing Sqoop as mentioned in https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/cdh_ig_sqoop_installation.html

Here are the results:

Step: Adding the CDH5 repository

```
   $ sudo wget 'https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cdh/cloudera.list' \ -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudera.list
--2019-05-30 11:30:44--  https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cdh/cloudera.list`

--2019-05-30 11:46:18--  https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/cdh/cloudera.list
Resolving archive.cloudera.com (archive.cloudera.com)... 151.101.36.167
Connecting to archive.cloudera.com (archive.cloudera.com)|151.101.36.167|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 271 [binary/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘cloudera.list.4’

cloudera.list.4                     100%[==================================================================>]     271  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2019-05-30 11:46:19 (16.7 MB/s) - ‘cloudera.list.4’ saved [271/271]

--2019-05-30 11:46:19--  http://%20-o/
Resolving  -o ( -o)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘ -o’
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudera.list: Scheme missing.
FINISHED --2019-05-30 11:46:19--
Total wall clock time: 1.2s
Downloaded: 1 files, 271 in 0s (16.7 MB/s)

$  sudo apt-get install sqoop
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package sqoop
```